# Related Manager is empty in one direction but not the other

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a method on a Django Model in which I create a new related instance by passing self into get_or_create:

```
def increment_or_create_item(self, product)
    item, created = Item.objects.get_or_create(cart=self, product=product)
```

Weirdly enough the item the does not show up in `self.items.all()` directly after calling the above line.
This works:

```
assert self == item.cart # does not raise
```

but this raises:

```
assert self.items.all() == item.cart.items.all() #does raise
assert self.items.count() == item.cart.items.count() #does raise
```

`self.items.all()` returns an empty QuerySet whereas `item.cart.items.all()` return the correct filled QuerySet.

I tried calling `self.refresh_from_db()` without success.

The models are really huge so I wont post them here but the important part is here i guess:

```
class CartItem(Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['product', 'cart']

    num_units = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'boxes.Product',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart,
        related_name='items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can this be?
Thanks!

Comment: Django Version is 2.0.6

Comment: Are you sure that the queryset is empty? Django's QuerySet class does not define an `__eq__` method, so comparisons are done on the basis of object identity; since those two querysets are separate objects, they will not compare as equal.

Comment: Yes I also printed them and can clearly see that one of them is empty. Actually how I discovered this is by comparing the `.count()`.

Comment: Can you show the models?

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i posted an exerpt, there are a lot of methods but shouldn't have much to do with this.

Comment: And where is the instance that this is being called on - ie `self` - coming from? Is it newly created, or queried from the db, or what?

Comment: ha great question! it is executed on a queryset method with an @transaction.atomic decorator. maybe this decorator prevents things from being written to the database or something?
i will try without the decorator and report back.

Comment: sadly the transcaction.atomic decorator doesn't seem to affect this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up digging deep into this with the debugger, and suddenly the asymmetry disappeared also `item.cart.items.all()` did not actually reflect the state of the database.

It seems like there is some kind of caching or refresh logic in the related manager that was getting in my way and I still don't understand.

I ended up making a fresh call to the CartItem model instead of going through the related manager and everything works great.

`CartItem.objects.filter(cart=self).all()`

instead of the above

`self.items.all()`